# Excel formula to separate text between "\"

Tags: excel, text, formula

I have a path in

A1 `C:\Users\fe\Desktop\01 Tur\2015\Kauk\Telu\Frame Report.pdf`

A2 `C:\Users\fe\Desktop\01 Tur\Deliveries\10 Toim\Alh\2005\Moot\CMC.doc`

A3 `C:\Users\fe\Desktop\01 Tur\Equip\Set\M-R\Kir\G3\sen.xls`

etc.

I would like to separate these paths to (example for A1)

A2 "Users" | A3 "fe" | A4 "Desktop" | A5 "01 Tur" | A6 "2015" | A7 "Kauk" | A8 "Telu" | A9 "Frame Report.pdf"

I have tried to play with

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("\";A1;FIND("\";A1;1)+2));A1;LEFT(A1;FIND("\";A1;FIND("\";A1;1)+2)))
```

but it is not so suitable for multiplication. Is there any better solution that can be copied for this case?

Comment: Use `Text to Columns` it is on the data tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"\",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]